# Notepad++ How to copy text, so I can paste into Find/Replace

Tags: notepad++, regex

The first line of my files is a single word (of varying lengths).
I wish to copy that word (and delete it), then paste it at the start of all the other lines in the file.

I can do the pasting part!, but how do I copy it so I can use it within Find and replace? Could somebody just give me a hint, to a method that would work, please?

Thank you

Comment: And you are trying to do this with a single regular expression? The copy, delete, and prepend in one step?

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't clear.  I'm trying to do the same process to a 100 or so files, so was trying to record a macro to do a) What I've described above and b) other bits of housekeeping.  So that I can then run the macro against all the files in a folder.

And I'd be happy to do the copy and prepend in one step, if that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do this is with a macro. Put the cursor at the start of line 1, and start recording. Now press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>, and then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Now press the down cursor key, and then <kbd>Home</kbd>. Now stop the recording.

or

Expand the recording out to iterate over the paste action, to the end of the file (last line).

Now when you open a different file, you can put the cursor at the start of line 1, and run your macro.